# Find the side lengths of right triangle.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$ABC$ is right-angled at $C$. Point $P$ is on AB so that $CP$ is perpendicular to $AB$. If $BP = 31^3$ and the lengths of $AB, BC$ and $AC$ are integers, determine all possible lists of side lengths for the triangle.

As $ABC$ and $PBC$ are similar $AB : BC = BC : BP$ and thus $BC^2=AB \cdot 31^3$.
Since $AB, BC$ are integers, $AB=d^2 \cdot 31$ and $BC=d \cdot 31^2$ for some integer $d$. Then by Pythagorean Theorem
$CA^2=AB^2-BC^2=d^4 \cdot 31^2 - d^2 \cdot 31^4=d^2 \cdot 31^2(d^2-31^2)$.
Hence, $d^2-31^2$ is perfect square.

Now how do I proceed? I'm stuck here.

Comment: If you have $d^2 - 31^2$ is a perfect square then you have $(d + 31)(d-31)$ is perfect squares. $\gcd((d+31), (d-31)) = 1,2,31,62$.  If $1$ you have $d-31 = m^2$ and $d+31 = m^2 + 62 = n^2$.  Solve.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks. I got AB=7,172,191 BC=462,241 CA=7,157,280.

Comment: Good.  It looks to be a really messy problem but the $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \implies a^2 = c^2 - b^2 = (c+b)(c-b)$ is a very good trick.  And noting $\gcd((c+b),(c-b)) = \gcd((c+b),2b) =\gcd((c+b), 2c)$ [so either both $c+b$ $c-b$ are even or relatively prime or have gcd(b,c) in comon] helps too.